# Wp Bakery vc_map param_group with array

Tags: wordpress, wpbakery

I am using param_group to show repeater item. This will shwo one item populated on start:

```
 'params'=> array (
   array(
    'type' => 'param_group',
    'value' => '',
    'heading' =>  __( 'List Items', 'pt-vc' ),
    'param_name' => 'price_list',
     // Note params is mapped inside param-group:
     'params' => array(
          array(
            'type' => 'textfield',
            'value' => 'sport',
            'heading' => __( 'Item name', 'pt-vc' ),
            'param_name' => 'itemA',
         ),
         array(
            'type' => 'textfield',
            'value' => '10',
            'heading' => __( 'Item value', 'pt-vc' ),
            'param_name' => 'itemB',
         )
      )
   )
);
```

How do I use this if I have predefined multiple array values?

```
$my_array = array(
    array('width'=>444, 'value'=>10),
    array('width'=>7777, 'value'=>33)
)
```

How would I pass data so I have multiple "repeater" items already populated?

For example I tried but it fails.

```
 'params'=> array (
   array(
    'type' => 'param_group',
    'value' => '',
    'heading' =>  __( 'List Items', 'pt-vc' ),
    'param_name' => 'price_list',
     // Note params is mapped inside param-group:
     'params' => array(
          array(
          array(
            'type' => 'textfield',
            'value' => '444',
            'heading' => __( 'Item width', 'pt-vc' ),
            'param_name' => 'itemA',
         ),
         array(
            'type' => 'textfield',
            'value' => '10',
            'heading' => __( 'Item value', 'pt-vc' ),
            'param_name' => 'itemB',
         ),
        array(
          array(
            'type' => 'textfield',
            'value' => '7777',
            'heading' => __( 'Item width', 'pt-vc' ),
            'param_name' => 'itemA',
         ),
         array(
            'type' => 'textfield',
            'value' => '33',
            'heading' => __( 'Item value', 'pt-vc' ),
            'param_name' => 'itemB',
         )
      )
   )
);
```

I even tried like this:

```
 'params'=> array (
   array(
    'type' => 'param_group',
    'value' => '',
    'heading' =>  __( 'List Items', 'pt-vc' ),
    'param_name' => 'price_list',
     // Note params is mapped inside param-group:
     'params' => array(
          array(
            'type' => 'textfield',
            'value' => array(444,777),
            'heading' => __( 'Item width', 'pt-vc' ),
            'param_name' => 'itemA',
         ),
         array(
            'type' => 'textfield',
            'value' => array(10,33),
            'heading' => __( 'Item value', 'pt-vc' ),
            'param_name' => 'itemB',
         )
       )
   )
);
```